# Unity C# PlayerPrefs / Unable to get it working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

just learning Unity/C# and having some big problems with saving PlayerPrefs. We need to use them although they were never explained, and all the codes that I've tried to make work from online sources have thus far failed me. Please keep in mind that I am still learning, and that all feedback would be greatly appreciated! Im trying to save the time the level was completed in (after everything has died on the stage) and keep a singular high score using a playerpref set function. here is my code so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playerScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public float currentHealth = 100;           // Player Hp
    private float restartDelay = 5f;            // Time to wait before restarting the level
    public float restartTimer;                  // Timer to count up to restarting the level
    public float thrust = 100f;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    private string textFieldString;             // Declaring a text field into a string
    public bool isFinished;                     // Checking if game has finished or not 
    public static float bestTime = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HighScore", 0);
    float gameTime;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        gameTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if(currentHealth <= 0) {
            currentHealth = 0;
            restartTimer += Time.deltaTime;

            // .. if it reaches the restart delay...
            if(restartTimer >= restartDelay)
            {
                // .. then reload the currently loaded level.
                Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
            }
        }
        //When all enemies are cured, calls this code

        if(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Length==0) {
            isFinished = true;
            //Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
        }
        if (isFinished == true) {

            bool isNewHighscore = false;
            if (gameTime < bestTime)
                {
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("HighScore", gameTime);
                Debug.Log ("HighScoreSet");
                }
                bestTime = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Best Time");
        }
    }

        void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {    
            // Reduce health
            if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
                        currentHealth -= collision.gameObject.GetComponent<ZombieBotAi>().zombieDamage;
                        rb.AddForce (transform.forward * thrust);
                }
        }

    //Event for running into healing bottles
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        switch(other.gameObject.tag)
        {
            case "Heal":
            ChangeHP(25);
            break;
        }
        //Destroys healing bottle after collision
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
    }
    //Displays Current HP on GUI
    void OnGUI(){
        textFieldString = GUI.TextField (new Rect (35, 500, 140, 30),"HP\t: " + currentHealth.ToString());
        textFieldString = GUI.TextField (new Rect (800, 35, 140, 30),"Best Time\t: " + PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HighScore"));
        if(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Length==0) {
            textFieldString = GUI.TextField (new Rect (600, 300, 230, 30), "You have won the game in " + gameTime + " seconds!");
        }
        if (currentHealth <= 0) {
            textFieldString = GUI.TextField (new Rect (600, 300, 230, 30), "You have been infected! Game Over !!");
                }
        }
    //HP cant go above 100
    void ChangeHP(float Change){
        currentHealth += Change;
        if (currentHealth > 100) {
            currentHealth=100;
                }

    }

}
```

Comment: You did not explain your problem. What problem are you having? What is not working and are you getting errors?

Comment: i didn't read your code, because you did not explain what the problem is. but after setting a value to PlayerPrefs, remember to call PlayerPrefs.Save() otherwise it won't be saved.

Comment: The problem is I have 0 clue what is needed to get the playerprefs to save, then to call on it properly to display the highscore when I need it.

Comment: Not sure what the question is and as far as i can see in the code as JeanLuc said if you dont save using PlayerPrefs.Save() your score will never load previous high score.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely fix these lines:

```
if (isFinished == true) {

        bool isNewHighscore = false;
        if (gameTime < bestTime)
            {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("HighScore", gameTime);
            Debug.Log ("HighScoreSet");
            }
            bestTime = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Best Time");
    }
```

PlayerPrefs doesn't work like that, at first you should assign variable with value. You have done this here:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("HighScore", gameTime);
```

Then you should call:

```
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

to save your variable, if you want to load the variable you should use the same key as you were saving it with.

```
bestTime = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore");
```

Hope this is what you was looking for.